# Pinch to zoom issues? MBA M1 256GB

Tags: trackpad, apple-silicon

I'm new to Macbook. I was using windows earlier. The touchpad of Macbook is so much better except the pinch to zoom function.

I usually keep one finger on the touchpad move the other (done using two hands) to zoom in while reading webpages i.e I don't really zoom by moving both the fingers outwards.

It seems to hit and miss. Sometimes it will zoom, sometimes not. Sometimes it'll be zooming and then start moving the arrow. It works only 1/10 times if I'm using the corners. It works 2/10 times if I'm moving the arrow and suddenly putting another finger to zoom.

Overall, it's not a smooth, but a very glitchy experience. Anyone else? Fix?

Comment: I read the instructions and it works fine for me - macbook pro and I have two.

Comment: So in my short testing I found that its vital to simultaneously touch the touchpad, i.e. put both fingers down at the exact same moment. When I would rest one finger on the touchpad and then start the zoom movement with my second finger it doesnt work.

Comment: and also not to touch the borders of the touchpad. So a finger can't enter from the outside; also, if a finger touches the border while zoom - it's game over, the zoom stops